# SDN4 Java configuration and indexes.auto=assert

Tags: spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm moved my Neo4j configuration from `ogm.properties` to Java config.

This is my current config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.domain.repository.neo4j")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jTestConfig {

    @Value("${neo4j.embedded.database.path}")
    private String storeDir;

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {

        Components.setDriver(new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService()));

        return new SessionFactory("com.example");
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {

        // @formatter:off
        GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(new File(storeDir))
                .loadPropertiesFromFile(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("neo4j.properties").getPath())
                .newGraphDatabase();
        // @formatter:on

        return graphDatabaseService;
    }

}
```

Right now I don't know how to properly add OGM property `indexes.auto=assert` to this configuration.

**UPDATED**

I have updated my configuration as following:

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.domain.repository.neo4j")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jTestConfig {

    @Value("${neo4j.embedded.database.path}")
    private String storeDir;

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {

        Components.setDriver(new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService()));

        return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "com.example.domain.model");
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {

        // @formatter:off
        GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(new File(storeDir))
                .loadPropertiesFromFile(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("neo4j.properties").getPath())
                .newGraphDatabase();
        // @formatter:on

        return graphDatabaseService;
    }

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration config = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();
        config.autoIndexConfiguration().setAutoIndex("assert");
        return config;
    }

}
```

but it fails right now with a following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not load driver: null.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 80 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not load driver: null.
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.DriverService.load(DriverService.java:57)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.DriverService.load(DriverService.java:69)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.Components.loadDriver(Components.java:158)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.Components.driver(Components.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.<init>(SessionFactory.java:44)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.<init>(SessionFactory.java:93)
    at com.example.domain.configuration.Neo4jTestConfig.sessionFactory(Neo4jTestConfig.java:37)
    at com.example.domain.configuration.Neo4jTestConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bde0f39a.CGLIB$sessionFactory$1(<generated>)
    at com.example.domain.configuration.Neo4jTestConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bde0f39a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b12a6805.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.example.domain.configuration.Neo4jTestConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bde0f39a.sessionFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 81 common frames omitted
```

**UPDATED**

This is my production configuration based on Bolt Driver:

```
@Profile("production")
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.domain.repository.neo4j")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConfig {

    @Value("${neo4j.server.database.uri}")
    private String serverDatabaseUri;

    @Value("${neo4j.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${neo4j.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        Components.setDriver(new BoltDriver());

        return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "com.example.domain.model");
    }

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();

        // @formatter:off
        configuration
            .autoIndexConfiguration()
                .setAutoIndex("assert");
        configuration
            .driverConfiguration()
                .setCredentials(username, password)
                .setURI(serverDatabaseUri);
        // @formatter:on

        return configuration;
    }

}
```

This configuration is working fine but I still have issue with Embedded based Java configuration.

Comment: Have you added the embedded driver as a dependency (Maven/Gradle)?

Comment: Yes. My original config in my question is working without any errors

Comment: I think I've seen this before. Although you only need embedded, what happens when you add all 3 drivers - http, bolt, embedded?

Comment: Right now I have both(Bolt for production and Embedded for tests). Everything is working fine except I can't configure Embedded with `indexes.auto=assert` at my Java config.

Comment: I'm looking at `Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not load driver: null.`. In the past there was a bug where all three drivers needed to be on the classpath, regardless of which was actually being used.  Have to check affected versions, but looked like it might've been that. It has been fixed for a while now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a blind spot in OGM configuration, so some jumping through hoops is needed.

There are 2 issues:

- driver class name must be set, otherwise you will get NPE
- even when you do that the driver you set by `Components.setDriver` will get destroyed in `new SessionFactory` (OGM thinks you are reconfiguring it)

For embedded db with custom config your `sessionFactory()` should look as follows:

```
org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();
// Register your configuration here, this will confuse OGM so the driver you set below won't be destroyed
Components.configure(configuration);

// Register your driver
EmbeddedDriver driver = new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService());
Components.setDriver(driver);

// Set driver class name so you won't get NPE
configuration.driverConfiguration().setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver");

// Configure auto index
configuration.autoIndexConfiguration().setAutoIndex("assert");

return new SessionFactory(configuration, "com.example");
```

It works, but beware it is a hack. Should be fine for tests though.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I can't find  `Configuration.Builder()` at `org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration`. I use `OGM 2.1.1`.  Also, I have updated my question where I have provided `Configuration` instance to `SessionFactory` but it fails right now with an exception

Comment: @alexanoid do you need that loadPropertiesFromFile on the graph database? If not you can configure driver class name and URI and OGM in the `Configuration` and will create the embedded database for you.

Comment: This is exactly why I have moved from plain `ogm.properties` configuration to Java based.. I need `loadPropertiesFromFile` in order to specify properties for https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-to-elasticsearch plugin

Comment: I have updated my SO question with my production Bolt based configuration. This config is working fine.. but I also need to configure auto index and for my Embedded Java Neo4j config.